# Uncertain of how to read OCaml function type signatures

Tags: string, list, ocaml

Could someone explain to me the following type? Specifically the return type.

```
string list -> (string * string * string) list
```

Comment: Its a function that takes a string list and returns a list of tuples where each tuple is composed of 3 strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `->` indicates a function type from one type to another.
- `string list` is the type of a list of strings.
- `string * string * string` is the type of a tuple of three strings.
- `(string * string * string) list` is the type of a list of those tuples.

Therefore `string list -> ( string * string * string) list` is the type of a function which maps from a list of strings to a list of tuples of three strings.